# Revisiting site optimization rules of thumb: JavaScript still necessary at the bottom with modern browsers?

Tags: javascript, optimization

I've been following web development trends for over 10 years now.  One of the biggest site optimization techniques i've always stuck to was that JavaScript goes at the bottom of your site.

The reasoning i've stuck with was that JavaScript blocks parallel downloads and each hostname may only download two components at a time.  This will negatively impact your site load times if added into the header of the document.

Now that i'm revisiting all my previous thoughts on site optimization i'm learning that none of this is actually true anymore with modern web browsers.

For example as of February 2015, Internet Explorer 11 can now have 13 connections per host name (no longer just two) and JavaScript no longer blocks parallel downloading!  This behavior is also true with ALL modern browsers.

While it's understandable that if you are not using JavaScript until the user interacts with the page and you should put it at the bottom anyway, is it as important now as it was before?

I'm looking through ecommerce sites to see the patterns they are using now:

http://us.karenmillen.com/Karen-Millen-texture-knitted-dress/dp/B00TH9FDQG?class=quickView&field_availability=-2&field_browse=6482174011&id=Karen+Millen+texture+knitted+dress&ie=UTF8&refinementHistory=subjectbin%2Ccolor_map%2Cprice%2Csize_name&searchNodeID=6482174011&searchPage=1&searchRank=-product_site_launch_date&searchSize=12

Looking at the architecture almost made me cry.  Over 60 external JavaScript files with a lot of them in the header, and almost none in the footer.

But looking at the network timeline the majority of all the JavaScript files are being loaded first at such blazing speed it really isn't affecting the rest of the site.  You can see all the parallel files being downloaded at the same time.

I'm assuming this was done for some particular reason so my long winded question is am I missing something?

With modern browsers how necessary is it to stick to our old rules from the past?  Should we be revisiting how we optimize sites now that we no longer rely on IE6 and rules that were made for browsers in that era?

Comment: This may be a bit of a tangent, but you might want to read this post on modern js loading best practices: https://www.igvita.com/2014/05/20/script-injected-async-scripts-considered-harmful/

Comment: These days, the amount of script usually vastly outweighs the actual content, so it probably doesn't matter. E.g. this page is nearly 800kB, but the HTML is about 70kB. About 200kB is CSS, maybe 100kB is images, the rest is script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, parallel downloads is just *one of the many concerns* in JS optimization.

While your modern browser *can* download more files in parallel compared to before, the browser still parses them in sequence. If script #50 (out of a 100) doesn't download, has an infinite loop or whatever, even if all 99 other scripts have finished download, the browser will still wait for #50 to execute before executing the other 50 after it (notable exception is when the script has a `defer` or `async` attribute).

Also, with a stalling script, your page will not render anything at all, just a blank white page. This is not good for user experience. Yes, I have seen code like this where you'll face a blank white page for 30 seconds because a dozen of scripts up in the head decided to be slow.

Just because the browser *can* do it faster doesn't mean you can skip the optimizations on the developer side. Faster is faster, and developers have been squeezing performance out of JS using optimization. Best if you stick to it.

Answer (score 1):

The optimization techniques have changed, but at the same time, browser's JavaScript runtime engines + user resources have gotten better too.  You could get more performance by revisiting your older code, true, but I doubt the gain in performance is worth the risk of accidentally breaking legacy code (especially when IE is involved).

Obviously, what your code does and who it is catered to makes a big difference in that decision.  For example, if a large percentage of your users are using mobile browsers, JavaScript performance is more important.

--edit--

As a sidenote, I want to mention that IMO, that website is not friendly to performance.  It isn't normal to load that many external (and embedded) scripts.  One of the better ways to load large amounts of JS files now is to inject them through AJAX.  Another is to have your server concat various JS files into one depending on your page, and then cache those processed files.