# JavaScript in classic ASP: Do the <script> tags still belong on the bottom?

Tags: javascript, performance, asp-classic, pageload

[Many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7751514/javascript-in-head-or-just-before-body), [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28574979/revisiting-site-optimization-rules-of-thumb-javascript-still-necessary-at-the-b) [developers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576370/where-do-i-put-the-links-to-my-javascript-jquery-files-in-my-html-file) wonder where JavaScript references (`<script>` tags) belong in HTML files. Nearly every authority figure seems to favor references placed at the bottom of the page, excluding jQuery and similar modules.

It's been over a year since I last touched ASP.NET and I have no prior experience with classic ASP. Does the classic ASP compiling/serving process benefit from `<script>` references that have been moved to the bottom of the page?

I've done some testing and it seems to help, but I can't be sure. If classic ASP *does* benefit from relocated `<script>` tags, is the payoff big enough to justify time spent refactoring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The placement of the `<script>` tag on the bottom of the pages has two key reasons:

- The HTML content is loaded *before* the JavaScript, meaning that the user sees your content earlier on
- Inside the script, you can assume, that all the HTML is already loaded and is available to the DOM (so no need to wait for it)

Server-side it doesn't matter where you place it, I think.

Comment: Placement of server-side `<script runat="server">` blocks have no impact as they are never rendered at the client. Using `<script runat="server">` is the equivalent to `<% %>`.

Comment: @Lankymart Honestly, I've never written any ASP / ASP.Net code, but does it really matter where this kind of script is executed inside the ASP-file in terms of performance?

Comment: @G_hi3: As Lankymart points out, positioning of the script tags is irrelevant, as the page is actually being built by the server. The position of the script tag within the page is basically where that particular part will be executing at. For instance, you may have a server side script tag (which is usually shortened to `<%`, your code in the middle and closed using `%>`) which renders a list box or even table for you at that point.

Comment: I was agreeing with you. The only real thing to bear in mind is breaking in and out of server-side code can have a performance impact.